# Issue with enum data type in create function

Tags: enums, sequelize.js

I have created "blogs" table with id(primary key), title ,created at ,updated at , status (with enum type having values "active,inactive,hidden" with default value "active")

create function on  Blog Model is working fine when giving status value from above mentioned set of values and empty value

```
const Blog = sequelize.define('blog', { id: { type: 
Sequelize.INTEGER, 
primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true }, text: Sequelize.STRING, 
status : { type : Sequelize.ENUM, allowNull : false, values : 
['Inactive','Active','Hidden'], defaultValue : 'Active' } }); 
Blog.create({"title" :"hello","status":"abc"}).then(result => {
console.log(result);
});
```

The above code inserted a new record in blogs table with status of empty value.but result object having status of "abc".How can I get newly inserted record ?

Comment: Share your model definition

Comment: Blog = sequelize.define('blog', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        text: Sequelize.STRING,
        status : {
         type : Sequelize.ENUM,
         allowNull : false,
         values : ['Inactive','Active','Hidden'],
         defaultValue : 'Active'
        }
    });

Comment: Please update the question to keep model definition as part of it.

Answer (score 3):

You should define `ENUM` like this:

```
status : { 
  type : Sequelize.ENUM('Inactive','Active','Hidden'), 
  allowNull : false, 
  defaultValue : 'Active',
  validate: {
    isIn: { 
      args: [['Inactive','Active','Hidden']],
      msg: "Wrong status"
    }
  }
}
```

In order to validate enum values you can use [per attribute validation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html#validations)

Comment: I don't need to validate.Create function output object  is not same as database inserted record.When I try to insert a new record with status value of "abc" , it inserted in blogs table with empty value but output object contain "abc".

Comment: It's not the same, because database does "validation" and does not allow other values to be inserted. Also by default `INSERT` query does not return newly inserted record, so `Sequelize` can't return it back to you either.

Comment: If you don't want to validate, but still want to be able to insert invalid data, then you can implement custom getter that will cut out all values except defined list. But I'm not sure if it's good practice.